# How to Show/Hide Column Fields Based on Other Fields - SharePoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a table with multiple columns in SharePoint and I am frequently adding new records into this table. The hard part of this, having a lot of columns make it difficult and causes confusing.

In below code, I hide all the columns and based on selection in the dropdown list, the fields will be shown to be key in. This test dropdown list consists of **Country, Fruit, Animal and Colour** it only gives me two option showing and hiding but I want to do same process for multiple fields. I am not sure how to do it. I will be grateful for your help, if you could direct me on how to do it.

Thanks

```
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="/SiteAssets/sputility.js "></script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function () 
{ // Get a the choice field 
var choiceField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Selection');

// Hide the target fields in form load

SPUtility.HideSPField('Country');
SPUtility.HideSPField('Fruit');
SPUtility.HideSPField('Animal');
SPUtility.HideSPField('Colour');

// create a function to show or hide a field based on the selected choice Field value 

var ShowHideField = function() { 
var selectedFieldValue = choiceField.GetValue(); 

if (selectedFieldValue != 'Country') {
SPUtility.ShowSPField('Country'); 
SPUtility.ShowSPField('Animal');} 

else if (selectedFieldValue != 'Fruit') {
SPUtility.ShowSPField('Fruit'); 
SPUtility.ShowSPField('Country');
SPUtility.ShowSPField('Animal');}

}; 


$(choiceField.Dropdown).on ('change', ShowHideField); });
</script>
```

---

@LZ_MSFT thank you for your help and I am sorry for misleading you.

I actually wanted to show the multiple fields based on particular selection in the dropdown list.

Let's say, as shown in the script above, when I choose country in the dropdown list both country and animal fields should appear or when I choose Fruit in dropdown list fruit, country and animal fields should appear. In above script, it works perfectly. However, I want to apply same process for more than 2 cases. Like, I want to choose Color and display only animal and fruit but I am not sure how to apply it after using If else statement.

If you could show me, I would be grateful for your help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code for your reference:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var fields=["Country","Fruit","Animal","Colour"];
    hideFields(fields);
    $("select[title='Selection']").change(function(){
        $(".ms-standardheader nobr:contains('"+$(this).val()+"')").closest("tr").show();
    });
});
function hideFields(fields){
    for(var i=0;i<fields.length;i++){
        $(".ms-standardheader nobr:contains('"+fields[i]+"')").closest("tr").hide();
    }
}
</script>
```

If the code not meet your requirement, I suggest you provide more information for further research.